# What engine code appears if catalitic converter is removed?

Tags: catalytic-converter

Someone stole a catalytic converter for my car. What code should reflect during diagnosis? I currently get P0401, and P0403.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

P0401/P0403 have to do with Exhaust Gas Recirculation (EGR) issues. Depending on where your exhaust was cut at and how the system recirculates exhaust gasses, this could be affected.

Codes for the cat usually show up as having issues with the O2 sensor. Those codes are P0150-P0175, depending on which sensor(s) are detected as being bad or out of range.